# How to Determine the Specific Meaning Behind Errors Using Fortify?

Tags: fortify

I've been told to use Fortify for the first time today, and I've gone through some basic instructional .pdfs, which were moderately helpful, but now I find myself stuck.  Basically the first few errors it found were simple hardcoded passwords and things like that. They were in the same project, and separate classes.

That was easy enough to document and explain. The second set were under a folder called Privacy Violations and were a bit more complex.  They were in a single project in one folder, but across multiple classes.

In one example Fortify said the Class Name 0/12 and (Shared Sink) I click it, it opens the class and shows me the problem, and if I click details explains it. It declares this 0/12. If I click any of the one's below it, these are not opened, and the same explanation is given except, these are not "Shared Sink, but 
"Privacy Violation".

The first was caused by logging, and the remaining 12 are method headers with parameters, so I'm more than a little bit confused, on what these have to do with privacy violations, and what I should be trying to document here.

Does anyone know of what I should be doing or a tutorial that might explain this?

Answer (score 0):

I see something similar with a Fortify scan from SCA 6.30 (rather old).  Based on the following: https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/Fortify-User-Discussions/Large-number-of-false-positives-String-Empty/td-p/1552553  it would appear to be a known bug and may be fixed in more recent versions of Fortify (SCA).